# Why does perl oneliner output depend on switch positions

Tags: perl

Can you please explain why perl switch `-en` does not work, but `-ne` works fine?

```
$ echo 123|perl -en 'print"$_"'
$ echo 123|perl -ne 'print "$_"'
123
$
```

Can you please give a link to documentation where such behaviour is described?

Comment: When a switch requires an argument that follows to the immediate right you must only put the argument to the immediate right. Putting a "n" after the "e" switch when the "e" switch expects an argument immediately afterwards cannot be what you desire.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After `-e` must follow perl code, but it follows only `n` which is not actual one liner, so `-en` can't work as you expect.

If you enable warnings with `-w` it will give you a hint:

```
echo 123|perl -wen 'print"$_"'
```

---

```
Unquoted string "n" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant in void context at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 6):

[Perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) is the documentation you need.

There you can find the synopsis (in bold the aforementioned `-n` and `-e`):

*perl   [ -sTtuUWX ] [ -hv ] [ -V[:configvar] ] [ -cw ] [ -d[t][:debugger] ] [ -D[number/list] ] **[ -pna ]** [ -Fpattern ] [ -l[octal] ] [ -0[octal/hexadecimal] ] [ -Idir ] [ -m[-]module ] [ -M[-]'module...' ] [ -f ] [ -C [number/list] ] [ -S ] [ -x[dir] ] [ -i[extension] ] **[ [-e|-E] 'command' ]** [ -- ] [ programfile ] [ argument ]...*

So as you can see from the above, the `-e` switch expects a `'command'` immediately after being called, making the `-ne 'command'` valid and the `-en 'command'` invalid.

Comment: Your point about `'command'` needing to immediately follow the `-e` is valid.  Your point about the order of options needing to mimic the order they appear in the synopsis is a red herring.

Answer (score 6):

Every time the Perl interpreter see the **-e** option it expects one line of program to follow. This means that any other option for a particular line of code must come before the -e option otherwise the interpreter will get *confused*. In short it will treat *any option after **-e** as command to execute*. Keep in mind that you can use several -e in one line.

```
perl -e "print qq(Hello\n);" -e"print qq(World\n)"
                               ^  
                             Not space needed here.
#Output
Hello
World
```

Comment: Why do you say "Not space needed here."? On my ubuntu system with Perl v5.10.1 it works with with or without space.

Comment: @bessarabov -What I meant to say was that since a space _is not required_ after the -e modifier, it will treat anything that comes after it as a _command to execute_ (even if what comes next is an option).